# Mounting hard disk of an old laptop through converter

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, lubuntu

I would like to access the hard disk from a broken laptop with my desktop computer running Lubuntu 14.04.3. I have connected it using a special cable/device that plugs into the contacts of the hard disk (removed from the laptop) and provides power as well - sorry, I don't know what it's called.

The hard disk is 'seen' on `lsusb` but doesn't appear anywhere mounted on the system.

Does anyone have any ideas how to mount this hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

Get the partition by using `sudo blkid`. lets assume it is `/dev/sdb1`

Now we need to make a mount location for it.

```
sudo mkdir /media/oldhdd
```

Now mount your device using such command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/oldhdd
```

Comment: Mostafa, I'm sorry but this didn't work for me. I think I found the disk listed on the hard disk at /dev/bus/usb/001/004 but couldn't use that in place of your /dev/sdb1 above. The blkid trick didn't show anything new when the disk was plugged in. The mount command wouldn't accept the usb address and returned a message along the lines of it is not a block device.

Comment: try `/mnt/oldhdd/` instead of `/media/oldhdd/`. see if it gives same error